# If while loop doesn't show first element

Tags: php, loops, oop, while-loop

I'm really stuck on this guys, and I know where the fault is but I can't seem to fix it.

The while loop itself works it's the if that is causing all the trouble.

Whenever there are 3 groups in the database it only displays 2 the strange part it will only display the items in the while loop. But the first item is somehow tied to the if statement.

```
public function get_group($user_id){

  $sql3="SELECT * FROM groups WHERE user = 
  $user_id";
  $results = mysqli_query($this->db, $sql3);
  $user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($results);

  if ($results->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
      echo "hello";
      echo "group :" . $row["group"] . "<br>";
      echo "groupdesc:" . $row["groupdesc"] . "<br>";
      echo "<a class='btn btn-primary' href='project.php?groupid=" . $row["groupid"] . "'>></a>";

    }
  }

  else {
    echo "0 results";
  }

}
```

It seems it can't output the first one the first one just keeps hidden.

Comment: you should post the output from that too

Answer (score 0):

You fetch your first row in this line:

```
$user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
```

And you do nothing with it.

And please do not mix procedural and object-oriented usage of mysqli.

Comment: You should add a note about not mixin  procedural and object-oriented useage of mysqli :)

Comment: You're brilliant! It shouldn't be in there! :O